# Flash messenger not adding messages to internal array ZF 1.12

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, flash-message

I'm using `Zend Framework 1.12` and my problem is that the flashmessenger is never receiving my messages. Here's my view helper:

```
    $flashMessenger = $this->_getFlashMessenger();

    //get messages from previous requests
    $messages = $flashMessenger->getMessages();

    //add any messages from this request
    if ($flashMessenger->hasCurrentMessages()) {
        $messages = array_merge(
            $messages,
            $flashMessenger->getCurrentMessages()
        );
        //we don't need to display them twice.
        $flashMessenger->clearCurrentMessages();
    }
```

And Here is my code from my controller:

```
    $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Job Created!');
```

Maybe there is a session issue going on here?

**Not quite sure what is causing the addition of a message to never receive the message within the flashmessenger**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I never heard about `view helper` such as `FlashMessenger` (may be custom solution) in ZF1. I know only about action helper `FlashMessenger` for getting|setting flash messages in controller`s actions.
But, if you want pass flash messages into views|layouts not like:

```
$this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
```

try do it with `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker`. In view:

```
$flashMessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
$messages = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
.....
```